# Good Reading/Bibliography

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, references, efficiency

Before posting this question, I searched CV for a similar question that could helped me, but I didn't find one. So, I'm sorry if this has already been asked before.

So, I'm self-studying from [Keith Knight's Mathematical Statistics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Statistics-Chapman-Statistical-Science/dp/158488178X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404408653&sr=1-1&keywords=Keith+Knight%27s+Mathematical+Statistics). At first, and by the table of contents, it seemed a good choice. It covers point estimation, likelihood estimation, efficiency of estimators, interval estimation and hypothesis testing.  However, after working with it a bit, I've found that there are many typos, and some of the exercises don't seem to be correct, like this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105600/showing-%CE%BB-vx-leq-min-%CE%BB-1x-cdots-%CE%BB-nx-hazard-function/105665#105665). And some of the calculus details seem to be left out. I'm not looking for a book that goes in too deep to the theoretical foundations, like Jun Shao's that uses measure theory. I'm searching for something like Knight's book, without the errors, and more formalized. If the book would take great care when stating the theorems and proving with them with a lot of detail, it would be great (specially when dealing with multidimensional cases).

So I've searched for a better bibliography and found two books that seem to be better. [Davison's Statistical Models](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Models-Cambridge-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521734495/ref=la_B001IQZI4I_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404407457&sr=1-1) which doesn't talk about efficiency that much or at all, and [Young's Essentials of Statistical Inference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Essentials-Statistical-Inference-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521548667/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1404408140&sr=8-1).

I would like to know your opinion on these books, and if you know of another book that you think it might be more useful please tell me.

Comment: Would you please clarify what specific topics you are hoping to find in your ideal book?  Is it limited to the set of items you mention from Knight's book?

Comment: It may not be limited to those subjects, but it would be nice to have them.